# How can I avoid name collisions when organizing imports or during autocomplete?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, import

When I use Eclipse's `Ctrl-Shift-o` to organize imports, `Ctrl-1` for quick-fix, or alt-space to complete a reference, I'd like to be able to specify a preferred package (or alternately ignore a list of packages) to avoid namespace collisions.  For instance, we always want java.util.List, but end up seeing the following dialog much too frequently:

[image: Annoying organize imports dialog]

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse supports negative import filters.  For example, you can filter all `java.awt.*` and `javax.swing.*` packages so that they never come up as an option. This can be done in the preferences under the `Java > Appearance > Type Filters` menu.

Incidentally, this is quite awkward, which lead me to file an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386125) to make it much simpler to filter unused types.